# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218 Laravel 5.1 using Knockout js and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Hi there I´m new in this community. I´m developing a web application with Laravel 5.1, and I want to call the method store of my model `Sale` from an ajax POST request, but I have this from console:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218

What could it be? thanks a lot.

these are my routes:

```
//Rutas para inicios de sesión
Route::resource('log', 'LogController');
Route::get('logout','LogController@logout');

//Rutas generales
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('index', 'WelcomeController@indexdos');


//Routes for users
Route::get('user/actualizar','UserController@actualizar');
Route::get('user/deleter','UserController@deleter');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');

//Routes for pacients
Route::get('pacient/deleter','PacientController@deleter');
Route::get('pacient/actualizar','PacientController@actualizar');
Route::resource('pacient', 'PacientController');

//Routes for medicaments
Route::get('medicament/deleter','MedicamentController@deleter');
Route::get('medicament/actualizar','MedicamentController@actualizar');
Route::resource('medicament', 'MedicamentController');

//Routes for doctors
Route::get('doctor/deleter','DoctorController@deleter');
Route::get('doctor/actualizar','DoctorController@actualizar');
Route::resource('doctor', 'DoctorController');

//Routes for dates
Route::get('date/deleter','DateController@deleter');
Route::get('date/actualizar','DateController@actualizar');
Route::get('date/bitacora','DateController@bitacora');
Route::resource('date', 'DateController');

//Routes for sales
Route::resource('sale', 'SalesController');`
```

This is the form that contents the values I want to send to `sale.store`

```
@extends('layouts.principal')
@include('Ventas.forms.barra')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
  {!!Form::open()!!}
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token()}}"      id="token"></input>
    @include('Ventas.forms.sale')
    <button id="btnAgregar" data-bind="click: $root.agregarVenta"    class="btn btn-success">Registrar venta</button>
{!!Form::close()!!}
 </div>
@stop
```

As You can see, I include the 'sale' form, where I include knockout js code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<table>
<tr>
<td>{!!Form::label('id_doctor_1','Cita a la cual se facturará: ')!!}</td>
<td><select data-bind="options: $root.citas, optionsText: function(item) {
                   return item.paciente()  + '  (Fecha: ' + item.fecha() + ' , Hora: ' +item.hora() + ')'
               },
                                 value: selectedDate,
               optionsCaption: 'Elija una cita...'"></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>{!!Form::label('Producto:')!!}</td>
  <td><select data-bind="options: $root.productos, optionsText: function(item) {
                                     return item.nombre()  + '  (Precio de venta: ' + item.precio_venta() + ' ,Existencias: ' +item.existencias() + ')'
                             },
                             value: selectedProduct,
                             optionsCaption: 'Elija un producto...'">     </select></td>

 <tr>
   <td>{!!Form::label('cantidad:')!!}</td>
 <td><input type="number" data-bind="value: cantidad"></input></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="btnAgregar" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
     <button id="btnAgregar" data-bind="click: $root.agregarProducto_venta"   class="btn btn-primary col-sm-8 col-md-offset-1">Agregar producto a la venta actual</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<br><br/><br><br/>
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: selectedDate"> <!-- Appears when you select something -->
 <div class="post format-image box masonry-brick">
 <!-- Begin Blog Grid -->
 <div class="blog-wrap">
  <table>
     <tr>
         <td><strong>Detalles de cita elegida</strong></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><strong>Paciente:</strong></td>
         <td><span data-bind="text: selectedDate() ? selectedDate().paciente : 'unknown'"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><strong>Producto:</strong></td>
         <td><span data-bind="text: selectedDate() ? selectedDate().producto : 'unknown'"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><strong>Cantidad:</strong></td>
         <td><span data-bind="text: selectedDate() ? selectedDate().cantidad : 'unknown'"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><strong>Subtotal:</strong></td>
         <td><span data-bind="text: selectedDate() ? selectedDate().subtotal : 'unknown'"></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><br><br></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td><strong>Productos a facturar</strong></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td colspan="2"></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
 <table>
         <thead>
                 <tr><th>Nombre del producto____|</th><th>Precio____|</th><th>Cantidad____|</th><th>Subtotal____|</th><th>Acción____|</th></tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody data-bind="foreach: productos_venta">
                 <tr>
                         <td data-bind="text: producto"></td>
                         <td data-bind="text: precio"></td>
                         <td data-bind="text: cantidad"></td>
                         <td data-bind="text: subtotal"></td>
                         <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeProduct">Remover</a></td>
                 </tr>
         </tbody>
 </table>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
<h3 style="color:#FAFAFA" data-bind="visible: totalSurcharge() > 0">
  Total (incluyendo medicamentos y cita): $<span data-bind="text: totalSurcharge().toFixed(2)"></span>
</h3>
```

And finally this is my `app.js` file, It is supposed that when I click on the button `btnAgregar`, the method `agregarVenta` makes an ajax request type POST, but it doesn´t work, what am I doing wrong? Again, thanks a lot.

File `app.js` (ajax method):

```
//Método para agregar una nueva venta al arreglo de ventas, y después pasarlo
//a la base de datos.
self.agregarVenta=function(){
  // crea un nuevo objeto Venta y después lo añade al arreglo.
  var id_cita = self.selectedDate().id();
    var venta= new Venta({id_cita: id_cita,producto:   self.selectedDate().producto(),
    cantidad: self.selectedDate().cantidad(),subtotal:  self.selectedDate().subtotal()});
    self.ventas().push(venta);

  for (var i = 0; i < self.productos_venta().length; i++) {
    venta= new Venta({id_cita: id_cita,producto: self.productos_venta()[i].producto(),
      cantidad: self.productos_venta()[i].cantidad(),subtotal: self.productos_venta()[i].subtotal()});
        self.ventas().push(venta);
  }
  var token = $("#token").val();
  var ruta = "sale.store"
  $.ajax({
     route: ruta,
     headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
     type: 'POST',
     data: {ventas: self.ventas()},
     dataType: 'JSON',
     error: function(respuesta) {alert("error");},
     success: function(respuesta) {
       if (respuesta) {
         alert("exito");
       }else {
         alert("error");
       }
     }
 });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//in route
Route::post('sales/AddItem','SalesController@AddItem');
?>

<script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'sales/AddItem',
  headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
  type: 'POST',
  data: {ventas: self.ventas()},
  dataType: 'JSON',
  error: function(respuesta) {alert("error");},
  success: function(respuesta) {
    if (respuesta) {
      alert("exito");
    }else {
      alert("error");
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

If you can use complete url in front of the route it'll be nicer.

Comment: I really thank You for your time, I followed your suggestion, changed my function and added the method AddItem in SalesController, but now my error is  "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161", 
at least now it's a different mistake :), my function is like next:        public function AddItem(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
       {
           return response()->json(["mensaje"=>$request->all()]);
       }
    }